# I have a problem with the import of modules from github to python

Tags: python, github, libraries

I have a problem with the import of a libraries from a github.

First, I install the github with this:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/CompVis/taming-transformers
```

Then I want to import the cond_transformer module from \taming\models\cond_transformer.py with this:

```
from taming.models import cond_transformer, vqgan
```

But he doesn't find taming:

```
    ----> 8 import taming
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taming'
```

Comment: Please [edit] to post more of the error message. Is it coming from the library itself or is it coming from your code?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  This fixed it for me.

!pip install taming-transformers-rom1504

Credit to: https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/x8h3xd/how_to_fix_cannot_import_name_vectorquantizer2/